# printing array in a specific sequence

Tags: java, arrays, vector

I am having some trouble to print the vector in a specific sequence. If anyone could help me with it. Thanks.

```
public static Vector sequence(int length, int start, int step) {

    /* to do
        length 1, start 1, step 1  => [1]
        length 2, start 2, step 2  => [2 4]
        length 3, start 3, step 3  => [3 6 9]
        length 4, start 4, step 4  => [4 8 12 16]
        length 5, start 5, step -1 => [5 4 3 2 1]
    */

    System.out.println(length + ", "+ start+ ", " +step); 
    Vector vector = new Vector(length); 
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
        int total = start+step; 
        vector.elements[i] = start+step;
        //System.out.print(vector.elements[i]); 
    }
    //return new Vector(length); 
    return vector; 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your attempt and tell us what doesn't work

Comment: System.out.println(length + ", "+ start+ ", " +step);
  Vector vector = new Vector(length);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
   int total = start+step;
   vector.elements[i] = start+step;
   //System.out.print(vector.elements[i]);
  }
  
  //return new Vector(length);
  return vector;

Comment: Why are they teaching students to use Vector?  If they want thread safety, they should be *externally* synchronizing an ArrayList (so that they understand what's going on), instead of using Vector.  Vector is archaic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply `step` with `i` and use the correct methods of `Vector` to add new elements, i.e. [Vector.add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add-E-). Also you better add a type parameter to `Vector`:

```
Vector<Integer> vector = new Vector<>(length);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
    int total = start+step*i; 
    vector.add(total); // add total as last element of the vector
}
```

Comment: now i get an error saying "the method add(int) is undefined for the type vector". how can i solve that?

Comment: @ReemuHossen: What vector class are you using? `java.util.Vector` should have a `add` method that takes `Object` and `int` would automatically be converted to `Integer`. Or are you using a java version < 5????

Comment: I am not using vector class, I am just using an array named it vector, and i my java version is > 5

Comment: Thanks for your help fabian, I found my way out,                             Vector vector = new Vector(length);
  System.out.println(length + ", "+ start+ ", " +step);
  int current = start;
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) { 
      vector.elements[i]= current;
      current = current + step;
     // vector.add(total); // add total as last element of the vector
     
  }

Comment: @ReemuHossen: You're using a custom `Vector` class and didn't give anyone information about it. That's why I couldn't provide a compilable example. Please remember to add details like this to your questions. Otherwise people will assume, you're using the classes from the [java API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).